# UnicodeDecodeError regarding 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError regarding 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 68455. I tried a few solutions by adding encode line. Still no luck. How can I resolve this error?

```
def create_HTML(config):

    in_doc = Path(config.doc)
    if config.o:
        out_file = Path(config.o)
    else:
        out_file = Path.cwd() / f'{in_doc.stem}_email.html'
    template_file = config.t

    # Read in the entire file as a list
    # This can be problematic if the file is really large
    with open(in_doc) as f:
        all_content = f.readlines()

    # Get the title line and clean it up
    title_line = all_content[0]
    title = f'My Newsletter - {title_line[7:].strip()}'

    # Parse out the body from the meta data content at the top of the file
    body_content = all_content[6:]

    # Create a markdown object and convert the list of file lines to HTML
    markdowner = Markdown()
    markdown_content = markdowner.convert(''.join(body_content))

    # Set up jinja templates
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
    template = env.get_template(template_file)

    # Define the template variables and render
    template_vars = {'email_content': markdown_content, 'title': title}
    raw_html = template.render(template_vars)

    # Generate the final output string
    # Inline all the CSS using premailer.transform
    # Use BeautifulSoup to make the formatting nicer
    soup = BeautifulSoup(transform(raw_html), 'html.parser').prettify(formatter="html")

    # The unsubscribe tag gets mangled. Clean it up.
    final_HTML = str(soup).replace('%7B%7BUnsubscribeURL%7D%7D', '{{UnsubscribeURL}}')
    out_file.write_text(final_HTML)

File "C:\apps\python\3.7.9\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 201, in get_source        
    contents = f.read().decode(self.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 68455: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x96 is in binary 10010110, and any byte matching the pattern 10XXXXXX (0x80 to 0xBF) can only be a second or subsequent byte in a UTF-8 encoding. Hence the stream is either not UTF-8 or else is corrupted. Since there is no encoding stated, you should try ISO-8859-1 (aka "Latin 1").

Comment: So what's the particular action I could take?

Comment: @codedancer Answer is telling you to try `f.read().decode("Latin 1")`